# GLM com valores de P não significativos

Tags: r, variáveis, regressão, análise-de-dados, glm

Meu conjunto de dados possui quatro variáveis: uma dependente (`Y`), e três independentes (`X1`, `X2` e `X3`):

```
> dput(dados)
structure(list(Y = c(29.1, 27.7, 28.2, 28.1, 27.3, 25.9, 27.2, 
30.6, 27.6, 28.4, 26.6, 28.1), X1 = c(29, 27.8, 27, 27.8, 27.7, 
26.6, 26.8, 30.7, 27.6, 25.4, 26.7, 26.7), X2 = c(28.3, 27.2, 
26.6, 27.5, 27.1, 26.2, 24.8, 27.2, 26.3, 23.9, 24.3, 24.1), 
    X3 = c(28.4, 26.5, 26.8, 27.4, 27.4, 26.3, 25.8, 29.2, 27.1, 
    25, 24.8, 25.3), z_X1 = structure(c(1.12601061016992, 0.235101116409105, 
    -0.358838546098108, 0.235101116409105, 0.160858658595702, 
    -0.655808377351713, -0.507323461724911, 2.38813239299775, 
    0.0866162007823022, -1.54671787111253, -0.581565919538313, 
    -0.581565919538313), .Dim = c(12L, 1L), "`scaled:center`" = 27.4833333333333, "`scaled:scale`" = 1.34693816645102), 
    z_X2 = structure(c(1.46389155419594, 0.723532607246269, 0.319700454364632, 
    0.925448683687089, 0.656227248432664, 0.0504790191102044, 
    -0.891796004280285, 0.723532607246269, 0.117784377923812, 
    -1.49754423360274, -1.22832279834832, -1.36293351597553), .Dim = c(12L, 
    1L), "`scaled:center`" = 26.125, "`scaled:scale`" = 1.48576579581036), 
    z_X3 = structure(c(1.29369391058265, -0.124393645248333, 
    0.0995149161986654, 0.54733203909266, 0.54733203909266, -0.273666019546331, 
    -0.646846955291328, 1.89078340777465, 0.323423477645664, 
    -1.24393645248332, -1.39320882678132, -1.02002789103632), .Dim = c(12L, 
    1L), "`scaled:center`" = 26.6666666666667, "`scaled:scale`" = 1.33983264445658)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Meu objetivo é utilizar um GLM para avaliar a influência de `X1`, `X2` e `X3` sobre `Y`. Como pretendo avaliar os *effect size* adiante, normalizei as variáveis explicativas antes de criar a fórmula do GLM:

```
> dados$z_X1 <- scale(dados$X1)
> dados$z_X2 <- scale(dados$X2)
> dados$z_X3 <- scale(dados$X3)
```

Em seguida, fiz o GLM, e notei que não houve relações estatisticamente significativas:

```
> fórmula <- dados$Y ~ dados$z_X1 + dados$z_X2 + dados$z_X3

> modelo <- glm(fórmula, data = dados, family = 'gaussian')

> summary(modelo)

Call:
glm(formula = fórmula, family = "gaussian", data = dados)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.3441  -0.5775   0.1998   0.5659   1.2082  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  27.9000     0.2511 111.132  4.8e-14 ***
dados$z_X1    0.3932     0.6634   0.593    0.570    
dados$z_X2   -0.9897     0.5763  -1.717    0.124    
dados$z_X3    1.2718     0.9426   1.349    0.214    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 0.7563262)

    Null deviance: 15.8200  on 11  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  6.0506  on  8  degrees of freedom
AIC: 35.838

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

No entanto, quando por curiosidade decidi fazer uma regressão linear à parte com cada variável explicativa, percebi que os valores de P para `X1` e `X3` (normalizados) foram significativos:

```
> summary(lm(dados$Y ~ dados$z_X1))

Call:
lm(formula = dados$Y ~ dados$z_X1)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.4573 -0.4792 -0.1374  0.6180  1.7799 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  27.9000     0.2628 106.160   <2e-16 ***
dados$z_X1    0.8275     0.2745   3.014    0.013 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9104 on 10 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4761,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4237 
F-statistic: 9.087 on 1 and 10 DF,  p-value: 0.01302

> summary(lm(dados$Y ~ dados$z_X2))

Call:
lm(formula = dados$Y ~ dados$z_X2)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.0207 -0.5717 -0.2569  0.6391  2.4029 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  27.9000     0.3411  81.783 1.83e-15 ***
dados$z_X2    0.4106     0.3563   1.152    0.276    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.182 on 10 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1172,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.02893 
F-statistic: 1.328 on 1 and 10 DF,  p-value: 0.276

> summary(lm(dados$Y ~ dados$z_X3))

Call:
lm(formula = dados$Y ~ dados$z_X3)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.7915 -0.3154 -0.1562  0.4124  1.4478 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  27.9000     0.2804  99.508 2.57e-16 ***
dados$z_X3    0.7620     0.2928   2.602   0.0264 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9713 on 10 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4037,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.3441 
F-statistic:  6.77 on 1 and 10 DF,  p-value: 0.0264
```

Qual seria o motivo desta diferença entre os resultados do GLM e das regressões separadas? Eu suponho que no GLM talvez a multicolinearidade entre `X1`, `X2` e `X3` possa explicar a falta de significância, mas não estou muito certo disso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que está a complicar o problema.

### `lm` e `glm`

No caso da sua pergunta, tem o modelo gaussiano generalizado com link identidade. Isto é equivalente ao modelo linear. Não vale a pena usar a função `glm`, que usa um algoritmo iterativo.

```
formula_lm <- Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3

fit_lm <- lm(formula_lm, dados)
fit_glm <- glm(formula_lm, dados, family = "gaussian")

coef(fit_lm)
#(Intercept)          X1          X2          X3 
# 11.9657747   0.2919041  -0.6660981   0.9492577 
coef(fit_glm)
#(Intercept)          X1          X2          X3 
# 11.9657747   0.2919041  -0.6660981   0.9492577 

deviance(fit_lm)
#[1] 6.050609
deviance(fit_glm)
#[1] 6.050609

summary(fit_lm)   # resultados
summary(fit_glm)  # equivalentes
```

---

### Multicolinearidade

Se há problemas de multicolinearidade, comece por calcular o *variance inflation factor*, [VIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_inflation_factor). Na prática é usada a tabela seguinte.

- Menos de 5: moderado;
- Entre 5 e 10: alto;
- mais de 10: muito alto.

Se o VIF for alto ou muito alto, remova esse regressor do modelo.
No R, existe uma função `vif` no pacote `car`.

```
car::vif(fit_lm)
#      X1        X2        X3
#6.400063  4.830177 12.923282
```

Deverá portanto remover a variável `X3`.

```
fit_lm_12 <- lm(Y ~ X1 + X2, dados)
summary(fit_lm_12)

rmse <- function(object, na.rm = FALSE){
  sqrt(mean(resid(object)^2, na.rm = na.rm))
}

rmse(fit_lm)      # 0.7100827
rmse(fit_lm_12)   # 0.7867373

AIC(fit_lm)       # 35.83755
AIC(fit_lm_12)    # 36.29786

BIC(fit_lm)       # 38.26209
BIC(fit_lm_12)    # 38.26209
```

---

### z-scores

Neste caso não motivos para calcular os z-scores, os coeficientes mudam mas as estatísticas do modelo são as mesmas, veja o AIC, deviance e o sumário.

```
formula_z <- Y ~ z_X1 + z_X2 + z_X3
fit_z <- lm(formula_z, dados)

coef(fit_z)
AIC(fit_z)
deviance(fit_z)
summary(fit_z)
```

No caso geral, nem sempre é necessário calcular os z-scores. Isso é verdade mesmo se as variáveis têm escalas muito diferents. Em, por exemplo, PCA. [Esta pergunta do R-Help](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2018-July/455326.html) é precisamente sobre esse tema. As respostas dos [Prof. Koenker](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2018-July/458539.html) e [Prof. Heiberger](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2018-July/458547.html) dão uma (muito) boa ideia de porque não os calcular.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação, @Rui Barradas, me ajudou bastante! Continuo somente com uma dúvida: Quando removo `X3` do modelo, ainda assim as demais variáveis continuam não apresentando significância no GLM, embora ao testar o efeito de cada variável explicativa separadamente, obtenho valores de P significativos. Qual seria, então, a melhor maneira de, no GLM, conseguir se observar essas significâncias?

Comment: @ArthurFilipe Em vez de GLM, quando há multicolinearidade tente [regressão LASSO](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/05/simple-guide-to-ridge-regression-in-r/) ou [regressão Ridge](https://rstatisticsblog.com/data-science-in-action/machine-learning/lasso-regression/). Se seguir is passos do R-bloggers sobre o LASSO verá que é a variável `X1` que é eliminada.

Comment: Ótimo material, muito obrigado!